# Some extra characters are being printed at the end of decrpted message

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
char arr[75][75];
char message[22], key[22], emessage[22], retMessage[22];
int findRow(char);
int findColumn(char);
int findDecRow(char, int);

int main() {
  int i = 0, j, k, r, c;
  k = 47;
  for (i = 0; i < 75; i++) {
    k++;
    for (j = 0; j < 75; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = k++;
      if (k == 123)
        k = 48;
    }
  }
  printf("\nENTER MESSAGE TO ENCRYPT\n");
  gets(message);
  printf("\nENTER THE KEY TO ENCRYPT THE MESSAGE\n");
  gets(key);
  // Encryption
  for (i = 0; key[i] != NULL; i++) {
    c = findRow(key[i]);
    r = findColumn(message[i]);
    emessage[i] = arr[r][c];
  }
  emessage[i] = '\0';
  printf("\nENCRYPTED MESSAGE IS:\n\n");
  for (i = 0; emessage[i] != NULL; i++)
    printf("%c", emessage[i]);
  //decryption
  for (i = 0; key[i] != NULL; i++) {
    c = findColumn(key[i]);
    r = findDecRow(emessage[i], c);
    retMessage[i] = arr[r][0];
  }
  retMessage[i] = '\0';
  printf("\n\nMESSAGE DECRYPTED IS (ORIGINAL MESSAGE):\n\n");
  for (i = 0; retMessage[i] != NULL; i++)
    printf("%c", retMessage[i]);
  getch();
  return (0);
}

int findRow(char c) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 75; i++) {
    if (arr[0][i] == c)
      return (i);
  }
}

int findColumn(char c) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 75; i++) {
    if (arr[i][0] == c)
      return (i);
  }
}

int findDecRow(char c, int j) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 75; i++) {
    if (arr[i][j] == c)
      return (i);
  }
}
```

Here is my code to encrypt and decrypt a message using Vernam Cipher. every thing is working fine except the decrypt part. some extra characters are being printed at the end of decrypted message.
for example:

```
 Message: 571635
 key: BYUg872e78
 Cipher: G`Vm;<
 Decrypted Msg: 571635a
 Expected msg: 571635
```

An extra character `'a'` is being printed at the end of Decrypted Msg.
How do I correct it in my code?

Comment: Your arrays do not hold pointers. You should not compare vs `NULL` but `0` instead. Or maybe `'\0'` if you prefer.

Comment: What is your intented result if the key is longer than the message? Or if the message is longer than the key?

Comment: @Gerhardh key should be equal to the message or longer than the message. As our project doesn't take a message longer than 6 digits, my key should be equal to 6 or can be more than 6. By default we will enter a key with more than 6 characters.

Comment: You are aware that your example key `"BYUg872e78"` is significantly longer than the message, are you? Not same length. And if the key is longer, you need to handle it properly.

Comment: Yes! Now that should be cut down to the length of the message.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks a lot!! it's Working fine:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your encoding and decoding is broken.
You do not properly care if the key and the message are equally long.

If your key is shorter than the message you only encode part of the message. Then you terminate the result at that position. Apart from losing part of the message this is fine so far.

If your key is longer than the message, you try to encode characters from the message that was not entered by the user.
First you will try to encode the terminating `'\0'` after the last message character.
This will fail because `findcolumn` does not return proper value and invokes undefined behaviour. You will probably store some "random" character into your encrypted message. 
Similar for any further character in the message.

When decoding you try to decode those random content and it is unlikely that you will get the initial `'\0'` again. Instead you get "random" results from decoding.

Listening to the warnings about not returnung a value from non-void function will at least show you when you try to encode or decode some fishy value and you can look why this could happen at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot..it helped! if the key is shorter, Concat the key until the length of both plain text and key are equal and if key is longer, break it to the length of plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what is the return value of  `findRow(c)` when `c` is not in `arr[]`?

Rollover for answer

> It missing - this leads to *undefined behavior* (UB) with `c = findRow(key[i]);` and others.

Enable all warnings to save time.

You may receive something like

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

at the end of `findRow(), findColumn(), findDecRow()`

---

Other issues exist.

Comment: Hm..I'm confused! Can you please make it easy for me?

Comment: @aashik Reading the mentioned warnings, what **exactly** is unclear for you? If a function is not a void function, it  **must** return something. Can you guarantee this for the functions mentioned?

Comment: Okay..If control reaches the end of a function and no return is encountered compiler assumes a return with no return value

Comment: @Gerhardh so now what should it return?

Comment: It is your design. You decide how to indicate that a character was not found. Maybe return -1 or any value you can distinguish from any other value you might return when you find an entry. And of course your calling function must check for this value and act accordingly.

Comment: @Gerhardh but how will that solve the problem I mentioned?

Comment: @aashik That is only step to improve your program. Your main problem should become obvious after reading my questions below your question.